# Having trouble with simplifying in Boolean algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

I want to solve this problem:

> $$(x . y . z + x . y + x)$$

Which turns into this when you group $x$

> $$x .  ( yz  +   y   +  1 ) $$

What I don't understand is why is there a "1" at the end? Does the last $x $ turn into a 1? If so, why?

My math book is unclear, I'm having a hard time.

Comment: Hi @sinan-samet, have you consider that the result x.(yz+y+1) stems from a basic factorization, simply...? If you take $(a∗a+b∗a)$ and factorize it with a, you will have $a(a+b)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the equation,

$x.y.z+x.y+x$

$=x.y.z+x.y+x.1$

This is basic boolean algebra, $[a.1=a]$    $[a+1=1]$

So if you group $x$,$1$ will be left at the end,as boolean algebra follow Distributive law.

Comment: Thanks a lot I had solved this problem later on but this makes it more clear!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the identity rule for the last `x` before using the distributive rule.